# baby's first classes and methods in java

Tags: java

Okay so working on my first assignment for my introduction to Java class. I have read the first 2 chapters in the book probably 6 times now and I've looked at a dozen various tutorials online and I'm still not getting what the problem is here.

I have class Student

```
//declare main class
public class Student {
// declare variables needed including ID_number, Credit_hours, points and GPA
private float ID_number;
private int Credit_hours;
private int points;
public float GPA;
// methods will go here
//method to return ID number
public float getID_number()
{
    return ID_number;
}
//method to set the ID number
public void setID_number(float ID_number)
{
    ID_number = ID_number;
}
//method to return credit hours
public int getCredit_hours()
{
    return Credit_hours;
}
//method to set credit hours
public void setCredit_hours(int Creds)
{
    Credit_hours = Creds;
}
//method to get points
public int getpoints()
{
    return points;
}
//method to set points
public void setpoints(int points)
{
    points = points;
}
//method to calculate and return GPA
public float setGPA()
{
    GPA = points/Credit_hours; 
    //return GPA;

}
//method to print the GPA
public float getGPA(float GPA)
{
    return GPA;

}
}
```

and then I have the class ShowStudent which is supposed to instantiate the Student Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ShowStudent
{
public static void main (String args[])
{
Student newStudent;
newStudent = getStudentInfo();
displayStudent(newStudent);
}
public static Student getStudentInfo()
{
    Student tempStu = new Student();
    float ID_number;
    int Credit_hours;
    int points;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Student ID Number >> ");
    ID_number = input.nextFloat();
    tempStu.setID_number(ID_number);


}   
public static void displayStudent(Student aStu)
   {
       System.out.println("\nStudnet number is:  #" + aStu.getID_number() +
          " While their GPA is " + aStu.getGPA());
   }
}
```

but eclipse is throwing all kinds of errors at me including the following:

"method must return type student" line 12 in showStudent

"Method getGPA is not applicable for this argument" Line 28 in showStudent

I just do not understand what is the problem here and I'm getting super frustrated with this.

Comment: Please show the **exact** error messages and clearly indicate which line causes each one.

Comment: `points = points;` in `setpoints` is wrong, it should be `self.points = points;`, otherwise you're just assigning the value back to itself

Comment: As for your 2nd issue, your method is `public float getGPA(float GPA)` which says it takes a float parameter but you gave none when calling the method `aStu.getGPA()`. It also doesn't really make sense to send in the GPA when the method itself is supposed to supply the GPA. If you already have it, why call the method?

Comment: For your 1st issue, your method is `public static Student getStudentInfo()` which says it will return a `Student` object but your method does not have a return - something like `return tempStu;`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Shouldn't Chat be `this` instead of `self`

Comment: @MadProgrammer why does points need to be this.point and none of the other setters?

Comment: @MichaelCividanes you use `this` to differentiate between your class attributes with that of the method argument/parameter if they are named the same - which you should probably do for `ID_number` as well.

Comment: When the class's variable and the method's parameter are named the same you need it, otherwise it is ambiguous. In the case of `ID_number = ID_number;` you need it, but in the case of `Credit_hours = Creds;` you don't.

Comment: @MichaelCividanes Look at the names of the instance fields and the parameters.  In most cases they are different, so the compiler can differentiate between them, but not in the case of `setPoints`, in that case, you MUST tell the compiler exactly what you're intention is, otherwise it falls back to local context

Comment: I would suggest being more consistent just for sanity purposes - either make all the setter parameters the same names as the variables and use `this` in all cases, or name all the parameters differently than the variables and don't use `this` at all. (at least in your setters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firsly you `getStudentInfo()` must return a `Student` object like this

```
public static Student getStudentInfo()
{
    Student tempStu = new Student();
    float ID_number;
    int Credit_hours;
    int points;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Student ID Number >> ");
    ID_number = input.nextFloat();
    tempStu.setID_number(ID_number);

return tempStu;
}
```

And secondly, you miseed up your `getters and setters` and some variable implementations in your `student` class. It should be like this

```
public class Student {
// declare variables needed including ID_number, Credit_hours, points and GPA
private float ID_number;
private int Credit_hours;
private int points;
public float GPA;
// methods will go here
//method to return ID number
public float getID_number()
{
    return ID_number;
}
//method to set the ID number
public void setID_number(float ID_number)
{
    this.ID_number = ID_number;
}
//method to return credit hours
public int getCredit_hours()
{
    return Credit_hours;
}
//method to set credit hours
public void setCredit_hours(int Creds)
{
    Credit_hours = Creds;
}
//method to get points
public int getpoints()
{
    return points;
}
//method to set points
public void setpoints(int points)
{
    this.points = points;
}
//method to calculate and return GPA
public float getGPA()
{
    return GPA;

}
//method to print the GPA
public void setGPA(float GPA)
{

    this.GPA = GPA; 

}
}
```

Comment: well at least now I know I was heading in the right direction. I had just made the changes to getStudentInfo() you said to make about 2 seconds before I refreshed the page and saw your response. 

So that did help with most of the problem. Thank you.  However, I am still encountering an error on line 29 of ShowStudent:
the method type is not applicable for the arguement()

and  on line 41 of  Student:
setGPA must return a type of float.

Comment: Think about the method name: `setGPA`. That should not really be sending anything back to the caller so the method should have a `void` return type instead of `float` - that means it does not return anything.

Comment: @csmckelvey wouldn't it need to be returned so it can called by other methods?

Comment: No, you would use `getGPA` to use it in other places - this is the core use of setters/getters. Setters just set the variable's value, getters give it back when needed. One for _setting_ values, one for _getting_ values.

Comment: @MichaelCividanes - here's a note for the far future, when you understand Java and OO programming better -- it is often useful to return `this` from setters instead of `void`, e.g. `public Student setGPA(float gpa) { this.gpa = gpa; return this; }` because that allows you to chain setter calls, like doing  `fred.setCredit_hours(20).setpoints(7).setGPA(3.75);`

Comment: @StephenP Thanks. I'll keep that in mind. At this point the problem is more learning java. I've been learning a lot about OOP via python recently, but java and python have about as much in common in how they work as the Russian and Japanese languages.